# How to find out what addresses a function accesses in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, dll-injection

I've done DLL injection on multiple programs but this one is challenging me. No matter how many times I've tried I can't find a list of static offsets to the values I need. Plus the values can change in quantity and thus it's much more effective to go straight to the function accessing them all.

In Cheat Engine I was able to find the address of the function that directly writes to these addresses. I used the "Find out what addresses this function accesses" option and found all the addresses I needed. However, I need to do this programmatically in C++ and have no idea where to even begin. And I have not been able to find any Google search results on the topic either.

Any information would be very much appreciated!

UPDATE: Just in case it's useful the function accesses them one at a time. Not multiple in the same call.

EDIT: The opcode is `mov [esi],ebx` `ebx` being where it's copying from and `esi` being where it's copying to. So I need to know the value of `esi` when the function is called. Hopefully this helps make my question less broad.

Comment: Unsure of how this is too broad. I asked a specific question. How to find out what addresses a function is accessing programmatically. Not to be a smart alleck but can someone enlighten me?

Comment: The "too broad" close reason is often used when, as in this case, a good answer would be too long.  There's no straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ah, okay. I understand, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply launch deassembler and trace all `mov edi` `mov esi` `lea` and other memory acess directives inside function. Also you can grab this information from dll using coff. If adresses are changing while execution continues try to use debugger and cpu view.
The strategy is that you need to get access to the call stack and the state of registers. This what i find in web maybe this will help you
https://www.gironsec.com/blog/2013/12/writing-your-own-debugger-windows-in-c/